# Session not saved for devices which are not browsers

Tags: java, android, rest, session, tomcat

I have a tomcat server, and I use it as a restful server.

With each rest request I need to provide a token. Once toke was provided I am storing it in the session. The problem is when I check some request via browser url the token saved in the session, but when I am doing this via some client (in my case android app) it always creates new session. It seems that each request from same client is handled as request from deferent clients.

Do I need to configure something in the tomcat? Why I am getting new session for the same client (when the client is not the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first request your container will normally tell the client to set a Cookie via a header like this:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=03f52fcdccdfd070be0ada8dw14b;
```

If the client wants to join this session he has to pass this Cookie with every request back to the server. Your Browser does this automatically for you. Other clients may not. 
Without this Cookie-Information every call from your Android App is new to the server.

Simple Example of using Cookie with [java.net.URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(loginUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
Map<String, String> formParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
formParams.put("username", "John"); // add your login Params
StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : formParams.entrySet()) {
    encodedParams
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"))
        .append('=')
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}
OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(encodedParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
String sessionCookie = null;
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    if (cookie.startsWith("JSESSIONID")) {
        sessionCookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(';')); // drop path, expires etc.
    }
}

// reuse cookie for next page
connection = new URL(nextUrl).openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionCookie);
connection.getInputStream();
```

Unrelated: Restful applications are normally stateless, means not based on a session-state.

Comment: can you add some code or reference to some example?